# Django Cannot Connect to SQL Server 2019

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-3.x, django

I have a Django Project and want to connect to SQL Server 2019. But I have a problem when doing migration. Here is the error message:

> django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: SQL Server v15 is not supported.

I'm using `Django 2.1.15` and `SQL Server Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5`.

Does it mean this Django version cannot using SQL Server 2019?

Comment: *"SQL Server v15 is not supported."* Is pretty explicit here. You either need a version of Django that does support it, or an older version of SQL Server.

Comment: According to [Django's website](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2019/dec/02/django-3-released/), 2.1 is completely unsupported and 2.2 is out of mainstream support. Looks like 3.0 came out end of last year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install specifically:

```
 pip install Django==2.1.15
   
 pip install django-pyodbc-azure-2019==2.1.0.1
```

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'dtabase_name',
        'USER': 'sa',
        'PASSWORD': '123456',
        'HOST': 'Your_host',
        'PORT': '',

        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Resolved. Thanks to another forum

Installed 2019 version: Django backend for Microsoft SQL Server and Azure SQL Database using pyodbc, compatible with SQL Server 2019

```
pip install django-pyodbc-azure-2019
```

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 19, 2020 - 18:52:09
Django version 2.1.15, using settings 'mdm.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

I'll create a new venv and share the procedure since the current one is a mess right now:

```
(venvAzure) luca@webserver:~/app/MDM_SQLServer$ pip freeze
certifi==2020.6.20
cffi==1.14.2
chardet==3.0.4
cryptography==3.1
Django==2.1.15
django-azure-sql-backend==2.1.1.1
django-mssql-backend==2.8.1
django-pyodbc==1.1.3
django-pyodbc-azure-2019==2.1.0.0
idna==2.10
msal==1.5.0
pycparser==2.20
PyJWT==1.7.1
pyodbc==4.0.30
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.24.0
six==1.15.0
urllib3==1.25.10
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just create an account to answer thi question. I lost a lot of time until can fix that.

To work with SQL Server 2019 i nedded to update the Django to actual version, 3.x and installed django-mssql-backend, django-pyodbc, pyodbc

In youd DATABASE definitions, add this line to work:

'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        },

Answer (score 0):

By adding the code below to **"settings.py"**, you can check which **ODBC Driver Version** to use. *In my case, it's **"ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"**:

```py
# "settings.py"

import pyodbc
print("This is " + pyodbc.drivers()[-1]) # ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
```

So for example, I use [**mssql-django**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qkjqf.png) to connect **Django** to **MSSQL(SQL Server)** with **SQL Server Authentication**. *I use **SQL Server 2019 Express**.

So, set the code below with **"ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"** in **"OPTIONS"** to **"settings.py"**:

```py
# "settings.py"

DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE':'mssql',  
        'NAME':'test',           
        'USER':'john',                      
        'PASSWORD':'johnpw',                
        'HOST':'DESKTOP-QVRCPTA\SQLEXPRESS',
        'PORT':'',                           
        'OPTIONS': { # Here
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server', 
        },
    }
}
```